# rgl: how to produce higher resolution snapshots?

Tags: r, graphics, resolution, rgl

For a book, I want to show two rgl images side-by-side, as in the image below. But the publisher wants images with at least 300 dpi resolution.

[image]

I created this using the code below to produce two separate images with `rgl.snapshot()` and then combined them into a single image with some other software.

- How can I amend the code below to save each image with higher
  resolution? The images I get are ~ 256 x 256 pixels, I think with 72 dpi resolution.
- Is there a different device driver I could use with `rgl.snapshot`?
- Is there some way to compose these into a single image using R?

```
    data(randu)

    # Figure 9.15 - 3D plots
    library(rgl)
    with(randu, plot3d(x, y, z, size=6, axes=FALSE, 
                       xlab = "", ylab = "", zlab = ""))
    box3d(col="gray")

    # left panel                   
    rgl.snapshot("randu0.png")
    # right panel                   
    rgl.viewpoint(theta = -3.8, phi = 3.8, fov = 0, zoom = 0.7)
    rgl.snapshot("randu.png")
```

Answer (score 2):

Save in `eps` format with `rgl.postscript`. Then convert to `png` with GhostScript (`gs`).

```
data(randu)
library(rgl)
with(randu, plot3d(x, y, z, size=6, axes=FALSE, 
                   xlab = "", ylab = "", zlab = ""))
box3d(col="gray")

# save in eps format
rgl.postscript("randu.eps")

# convert to png
cmd <- 
  "gs -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dEPSCrop -sDEVICE=png16m -r600 -sOutputFile=randu.png randu.eps"
system(cmd)
```

You can use ImageMagick to append two images.

Comment: Thx; I'll try this.  In the past, I always had troubles with `eps` format and `gs` conversion. Your answer with the cmd args to `gs` gets a +1 from me.

Comment: That's definitely the best way, when it works:  the problem is that `rgl.postscript` isn't perfect at rendering everything that `rgl` can draw.  A more reliable but slightly poorer quality approach is to grow your window as big as your system allows, using `par3d(windowRect = c(0, 0, 1000, 1000))` for example.  On some systems you'll need to insert `Sys.sleep(1)` after the resizing to let the window finish resizing before you take the snapshot.